# Regular Expression in .net for Key Value Pairs not fully separated

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string like:

```
abcd+value1defg+value2hijk+value3
```

the structure is always `\w{4}\+.*` but how can I look ahead to the next `\w{4}\+`

I need a regular expression to extract the following values:

```
Match 1:
  abcd (key)
  value1 (value)
Match 2:
  defg (key)
  value2 (value)
Match 3:
  hijk (key)
  value3 (value)
```

I already pulled out some of my hair. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\w{4})\+(\w+)(?=\w{4}\+|$)
```

Try this.Grab the cpatures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/4

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a separator character between your key value pairs, then splitting the string on that rather than using RegEx